# If-Then clause using cells in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

My situation:

I have some columns in excel containing different values, for each row I want to check column 1,2,3,etc and then I need an if-then clause that works like this:

```
if (value in colum1=="something")
then 
fill cell x with "something else"
```

I'm not asking how to do it in details, but if you could tell me what excel functions I should look into to make it possible it'd be great. (I have never worked with excel before and I didnt find much googling)

Comment: Please post your original code and your problem. It is impossible for us to just answer you by seeing your syntax.

Comment: Um, Excel has a IF() statement that you can put into cell x.

Comment: @ScottCraner But the question here is not `IF` but rather how :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen <sarcasm> but the op stated `I'm not asking how`. </sarcasm>  :) I know I took it out of context but... 8P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Into Cell X enter the following formula:

```
=IF(A1="something", "val if true", "val if false")
```

The general syntax for Excel's `IF` function is:

```
=IF([condition], [value if TRUE], [value if FALSE])
```

Comment: This is what i woudlve though, but upon entering

=IF(A1="yes", "ok")

excel says "theres a problem with this formula.

It works fine if i replace "yes" and "ok" with numbers though

Comment: What regional settings do you have? On some Excel versions you need to use ; as the function delimiter

Comment: Actually i found the mistake, in the german version of excel the values are seperated by a semicolon and the function name is actually translated, so its 

"=WENN()"

Comment: @Fel If you want to retain the original value if `A1` does _not_ equal yes, then try this: `=IF(A1="yes", "ok", A1)`

Answer (score 0):

Place this in the cell which you would like filled:

```
=IF(A1="Something","Something","NotSomething")
```

You can drag this down or across cells as well. The cell value will update itself.